# How do I record time of packets in file using wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I want to record time of packets in file using Wireshark.

Any hints about how I can do this?

Comment: Pretty sure every packet received is always time-stamped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the capture menu, selection options (Ctrl+K). In the dialog that opens, you are able to select a file in which to store the output of a capture.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am able to store the file, now I want to filter the network packets through its header, can you give me hints like that filter?

Comment: if you are referring to filtering what packets actually go into the file, there are heaps of instructions and special formatting strings that are unique to Wireshark, so you will need to read up on those. The wireshark manual has instructions, as well as here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters